# Using Mate's RemoteObjectInvoker with C# classes

Tags: c#, apache-flex, actionscript-3, amf, remoteobject

I'm using the Mate framework for Flex and communicating with a server running C#. I'm having trouble mapping C# classes to ActopnScript classes. I've got it working fine for simple classes and built in datatypes.

If I have a C# method in my API that returns a API.Foo.Result< API.Foo.Bar > what name do I use for my RemoteClass alias? Do I need to make a separate ActionScript class for each variation of the API.Foo.Result?

How do I call C# method that takes a class as a parameter? Making an ActionScript class with members with the same names doesn't seem to work.

What is the best way to handle C# classes that contain arrays of objects? The seem to get converted to ArrayCollections of Object. Is there a way to get them converted to an ArrayCollection of my specific class?

Comment: You have to provide more detail..what are you using on the server side in order to be able to do remote calls ? Weborb? Fluorine?

Comment: I'm using FluorineFX-3.5

Comment: I updated my question because the formatting made part of the question disappear. In the first part, I'm trying to return a generic class, that's why I'm not sure how to do the remote class annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question/Answer

**If I have a C# method in my API that returns a API.Foo.Result what name do I use for my RemoteClass alias?**

The AS class name could be anything. But you have to specify the C# class name inside the remote class annotation.

```
[RemoteClass(alias="API.Foo.Result")]
public class Result VO
{
    ...
}
```

[More info...](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html)

---

**Do I need to make a separate
ActionScript class for each variation
of the API.Foo.Result?**

Briefly, Yes. I didn't found info about inheritance for classes mapped in FlourineFX. probably you are going to need to map each one individually.

---

**How do I call C# method that takes a
class as a parameter?**

There is an example using a web service that receive a DTO [Here](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html).

Just like using an AS RemoteObject. ; )

---

**What is the best way to handle C#
classes that contain arrays of
objects?**

[This](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html) is the type mapping for FlourineFX (including collections). For Flex remoting this is a great [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756755/how-do-i-get-a-strongly-typed-collection-from-blazeds).

And they used them transparently in the [documentation](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html).

---

Hope it helps you...